# Parse tab delimited file with more than one table

Tags: c#, csv

Can anyone recommend a good method using c# (maybe filehelper) that would let me parse a file formatted like this in c#?

```
%T  person
%F  id  name    address city
%R  1   Bob 999 Main St Burbank
%R  2   Sara    829 South st    Pasadena
%T  houses
%F  id  personid    housetype  Color
%R  25  1       House   Red
%R  26  2       condo   Green
```

I'd like to get the two tables into a data table or something that I could query with linq.

The file is tab delimited

Comment: how about splitting into multiple TSVs based on %T identifier and then parsing each TSV using a library like [FileHelpers](http://www.filehelpers.com/).

Comment: How do you recommend splitting into multiple TSV's?  Do you mean to do this in memory, classes, or datatables?

Answer (score 0):

Sample parser for this kind of data

```
public IEnumerable<Dictionary<string, string>> Parse(TextReader reader)
{
    var state = new State { Handle = ExpectTableTitle };
    return GenerateFrom(reader)
        .Select(line => state.Handle(line.Split('\t'), state))
        .Where(returnIt => returnIt)
        .Select(returnIt => state.Row);
}

private bool ExpectTableTitle(string[] lineParts, State state)
{
    if (lineParts[0] == "%T")
    {
        state.TableTitle = lineParts[1];
        state.Handle = ExpectFieldNames;
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Expected %T but found '"+lineParts[0]+"'");
    }
    return false;
}

private bool ExpectFieldNames(string[] lineParts, State state)
{
    if (lineParts[0] == "%F")
    {
        state.FieldNames = lineParts.Skip(1).ToArray();
        state.Handle = ExpectRowOrTableTitle;
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Expected %F but found '" + lineParts[0] + "'");
    }
    return false;
}

private bool ExpectRowOrTableTitle(string[] lineParts, State state)
{
    if (lineParts[0] == "%R")
    {

        state.Row = lineParts.Skip(1)
            .Select((x, i) => new { Value = x, Index = i })
            .ToDictionary(x => state.FieldNames[x.Index], x => x.Value);
        state.Row.Add("_tableTitle",state.TableTitle);
        return true;
    }
    return ExpectTableTitle(lineParts, state);
}

public class State
{
    public string TableTitle;
    public string[] FieldNames;
    public Dictionary<string, string> Row;
    public Func<string[], State, bool> Handle;
}

private static IEnumerable<string> GenerateFrom(TextReader reader)
{
    string line;
    while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        yield return line;
    }
}
```

Then just convert/map each resultant Dictionary to one of your domain objects based on the _tableTitle entry.

Here's a test harness using your sample data. To read from a file, pass in a StreamReader instead of a StringReader.

```
const string data = @"%T\tperson
%F\tid\tname\taddress\tcity
%R\t1\tBob\t999 Main St\tBurbank
%R\t2\tSara\t829 South st\tPasadena
%T\thouses
%F\tid\tpersonid\thousetype\tColor
%R\t25\t1\tHouse\tRed
%R\t26\t2\tcondo\tGreen";

var reader = new StringReader(data.Replace("\\t","\t"));

var rows = Parse(reader);
foreach (var row in rows)
{
    foreach (var entry in row)
    {
        Console.Write(entry.Key);
        Console.Write('\t');
        Console.Write('=');
        Console.Write('\t');
        Console.Write(entry.Value);
        Console.WriteLine();
    }
    Console.WriteLine();
}
```

Output:

```
id    =    1
name    =    Bob
address    =    999 Main St
city    =    Burbank
_tableTitle    =    person

id    =    2
name    =    Sara
address    =    829 South st
city    =    Pasadena
_tableTitle    =    person

id    =    25
personid    =    1
housetype    =    House
Color    =    Red
_tableTitle    =    houses

id    =    26
personid    =    2
housetype    =    condo
Color    =    Green
_tableTitle    =    houses
```